# btrfs sync and deferred operations - is the special ioctl required?

Tags: linux, btrfs, synchronization

I am periodically getting kernel errors on my external HDD btrfs filesystem. I use [`btrbk`](https://github.com/digint/btrbk/) to backup snapshots to my external HDD, and the errors relate to subvolumes.

I'm meticulously unmounting the filesystems before removing the device.

[`man btrfs-filesystem`](https://manned.org/btrfs-filesystem) says:

> ```
>   sync <path>
>        Force a sync of the filesystem at path. This is done via a special
>        ioctl and will also trigger cleaning of deleted subvolumes. Besides
>        that it’s equivalent to the sync(1) command.
> ```

Does this mean that if I run `umount /media/backup-disk` there may still be a `subvolume delete` operation in progress?

Given this is not a normal `sync`, will the `umount` wait for completion or pause this process, or will the kernel carry on writing to the device after `umount` succeeds? If it pauses, should it resume correctly on the next `mount`?

Are there any other considerations I should be aware of before removing a device containing a btrfs filesystem?